# How can Index be used when applying function to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Say if I have an index on a DateTime column (named [Timestamp]), and then I use the column in the following query,

```
SELECT [Id], [Timestamp]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE FORMAT([Timestamp], 'yyyy/MM/dd HH') = '2022/12/14 01'
ORDER BY [Id]
```

Will the index on the `[Timestamp]` column be used when executing this query? Otherwise, what'll be a good strategy to go for improving the performance of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because you are calling a function on your column, so the index cannot know in advance which values meet your criteria. You need to avoid manipulating the column values in your `WHERE` clause at all costs. The best approach for comparing datetimes is usually a window compare e.g.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime2(0) = '2022/12/14 01:00:00'
    , @EndDate datetime2(0) = '2022/12/14 02:00:00';

SELECT [Id], [Timestamp]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
WHERE [Timestamp] >= @StartDate AND [Timestamp] < @EndDate
ORDER BY [Id];
```

Note: You can check whether the index is used by inspecting the execution plan.